# Why cant i access the controller from a helper with att_reader :controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, helper

I have been trying to figure out why i cannot access the :controller variable from my rails helper. Is there anything special going on with calling `att_reader :controller` inside a helper class?

This is a rails 4 application and this is my code:

```
class TicketFormTag < Liquid::Block

    include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
    include ActionView::Context

    #include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

    attr_reader :controller

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
        super

    end

    def render(context)

        @controller = context.registers[:controller]

        super(context).html_safe
        form_tag('#') do

        end
    end

    delegate :form_authenticity_token, :request_forgery_protection_token, :protect_against_forgery?, to: :controller
end
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Well if i try to just output the value of ":controller", i get "controller" (without the : )

Comment: where is :controller defined?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't controller defined by rails? I thought i called attr_reader to get access to protect_against_forgery?

Comment: @jkeuhlen - did you mean "where is `@controller` defined?", because symbols don't need to be pre-defined.

Comment: @jefflunt Symbols don't need to be pre-defined but I don't believe that symbol is pointing at the `@controller` variable like he thinks it is. So I was trying to lead the OP down the path to see that since `:controller` isn't being defined anywhere it defaults the symbol to the the string it contains, i.e. `"controller"`

Comment: Wait - is the OP talking about the use of `@controller` or `context.registers[:controller]` ?

Comment: Hmm i think both. I'm trying to use :controller to define @controller. But I'm also trying to use :controller in the end of the class to delegate "protect_against_forgery?" etc. However i haven't written this my self, so I'm not sure. The only thing I'm sure about is that i need access to the different form security methods to get the form tag to work in the helper.

Comment: To clarify, the real problem I'm trying to solve is how to use a form helper inside a Liquid block definition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809907/why-cant-i-access-the-controller-from-a-helper-with-att-reader-controller However there doesn't seem to be many people who can answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

**I Just read a guide about module, class and object in ruby:**

I think in: `def initialize`
there must be @controller = "What you want to access with attr_reader: controller. Means

```
def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
    super
    @controller = something
end
```